# Event Observer for import with magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, database, event-observer, sql, magmi

I created an event observer to report the creation of new magento products, but the observer doesn't work when the products are created by importing Magmi.

My magento version is 1.9.3.9

This is the config.xml

```
    <global>
        <models>
            <wally_logproductupdate>
                <class>Wally_LogProductUpdate_Model</class>
            </wally_logproductupdate>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <wally_logproductupdate>
                        <class>wally_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeSave</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </wally_logproductupdate>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
```

This is the Observer:

```
class Wally_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{
    protected $isNew = false;

    public function beforeSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->isNew = true;
            $this->afterSave($observer);
        }
    }

    public function afterSave($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if ($this->isNew) {
            $name = $product->getName();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $price = $product->getPrice();

            Mage::log("[{$name} ({$sku}) {$price}] aggiornato", null, 'product-updates.log');           
        }
    }
}
```

Is it the right way or do I have to work in other ways to import products using magmi?

Answer (score 1):

As per official wiki of `magmi`:

*Magmi is a Magento Mass Importer developed as a magento DATABASE client, (ie not a magento extension) , **that operates directly in SQL.***

So magmi runs raw query and any event **will not** dispatched during import by magmi!

Comment: Yes, these days I have read that magmi does not pass by the orm model of magento, so what is the best solution to get the id of new products imported from magmi?

Comment: You can add additional attribute while import from magmi say `is_magmi_new` and set value to 1 while import.

after import you can create a script on root and check for all product `is_magmi_new` with value 1. 

once you done you goal, you can set value to 0

Comment: Good idea, I try to do it :D

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: No @Pawan I was not able to do it this way, in the end I opted to create a custom event and pass everything to an observer who retrieves product ids based on the date of creation